# Wordpress - Plugin. using remove_action for favorite_actions

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

Learning php, figure as well as following tutorials doing some practical useful stuff is import. So a wordpress plugin....

Trying to remove the favorite actions box that you get in the wordpress admin header.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Hide Favorite Actions
Plugin URI: http://www.mysite.com
Description: Allows you to remove the Screen Options and Help tabs from view
Author: Tai Havard
Version: 1.0
Author URI: 
*/

add_action('admin_menu','removeHelpAndScreenOptions');

function removeHelpAndScreenOptions()
{
remove_action('favorite_actions');  
}

?>
```

Plugins activated, function runs, I'm just not sure how to get hold of the favorite_actions correctly and wether remove_action is the correct function for use with the favorite_actions hook.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's how remove action works:

```
remove_action( 'hook_name', 'function_name' );
```

That says you want to remove the function `function_name` from the hook `hook_name`. I don't know what the hook and function are fore removing help and screen options, though. If I remember correctly, those tabs are hardcoded into the actual admin pages.

Comment: Yeah, I double checked the code on this one. There are ways to remove the text from the help screen or screen options screen, but no way to actually remove the tabs.

Answer (score 1):

I used that code and got an error in a template.php (presumably expecting an array) The box disappears if you return with an empty element, something like this:

```
add_filter('favorite_actions', 'no_fav');
function no_fav($actions) {
    $actions = array(
        '' => array(__(''), '')
    );
    return $actions;
}
```

I just deleted the strings, somebody could probably write a more elegant empty array.

Answer (score 0):

In your plugin just add

```
function rb_ax() {
return;
}
add_filter( 'favorite_actions', 'rb_ax' );
```

And you're done.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me, wp 3.0.5

```
/**
 * Remove "Favorite actions" from Admin
 */
add_filter('favorite_actions', 'no_fav');
function no_fav($actions) {
    return array();
}
```

I put it in functions.php, but it would probably work fine as a plugin.

returning nothing (void?) works, but writes `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()...`